# recreate a round slider with a dot inside CSS instead of picture

Tags: html, css

Trying since 1 hour now to recreate this slider:

Slider

[image: 1]

This is mir progress so far:

[image: 2]

its a Span element i try to style - here are my code attempts (researched alot , found outline, shadow, but nothing seems to get the job done)

```
left: 0%;
background: rgb(94, 173, 61);
border-radius: 50%;
width: 5px;
height: 5px;
top: 0%;
outline: 3px red solid;
outline-offset: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px red;
box-shadow: spread 5px;
```

progress with code

[image: 3]

Is it possible with css or should i just use a picture ?

ps. in the preview dosent show the pictures only a link to it. hope it works in the posted question

Comment: can u share full code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recreate the range finder by adding a box-shadow and set it to inset at the end.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 145px;
  height: 145px;
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 4px solid green;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 01px 25px white inset;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #04AA6D;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Custom Range Slider</h1>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p>Default range slider:</p>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">
  
  <p>Custom range slider:</p>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bencepiatrik/h6Lcw05k/4/

Comment: I modified it just to the basic level, feel free to customize it !

Comment: u sir, are a true man of culture - thx alot

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help